# React Navigation - memory increases when I navigate between screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I use React-Navigation v4 (Stack Navigator)  with react-native-screens v2.0.0-alpha.6 and I have noticed a memory increase when I navigate between screens.

For example, if I populate a list with Items and navigate to an Item Page memory adds up 5mb. Even If I go back, memory is not released. It's like adding the same page in stack, even I have visited before. Is this a bug? Can I remove same screen names from stack?

Memory Results Here ->
[Memory Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHTSS.png)

Comment: do you do navigation.push() or navigation.navigate()?

Comment: navigation.navigate('ScreenName')

Answer (score 0):

`navigation.navigate()` for the screen rendered for 1st time it adds the whole screen in its stack , so its memory increases, but when you again navigate to same page, it wont take up so many memory since it doesnt again push the screen to the navigation stack.You can clear `Stacknavigator` by

```
NavigationActions.reset(
                 {
                    index: 0,
                    actions: [
                      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Menu'})
                    ]
                  }).
```

So thats the difference, feel free for doubts

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but when I navigate for the first time to a screen it increases ram by 5mb and when I revisit the same page it increases ram by 5 mb again. It's like adding the same page in stack, even I have visited before (Im' talking about visiting Items Page in the list). Is there a case to be react-native-screens (NativeNavigator) bug?

Answer (score -1):

Use `navigation.goBack('ScreenName')` instead of `navigation.navigate('ScreenName')` and check bellow link
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html

Comment: I don't want to go back, I want to go forward

Comment: sorry in your stack navigator use navigation.goBack() instead of  navigation.navigate('')  as a example  ` const commonNavigationStack = {
  Search: {
    screen: SearchScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        headerTitle: (
          <Header
            title={false}
          />
        ),
        headerLeft: (
          <HeaderBackButton
            tintColor={'#fff'}
            onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
          />
        ),
      };
    },
  },
}`

Comment: I want to navigate from FlatList Item to Item's Page, I don't want to go back.